# Slow boot into Ubuntu only when external HD is connected

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Have worked with a Ubuntu 22.04 system for months now without issue but have recently found booting into Ubuntu to take much longer than normal (~60s to >10 mins).

Through some trial and error have determined the issue only crops up when one of my external HDs is connected via USB to my laptop.

How would I go about debugging the underlying cause of this to address it?  Like I'd said, this only started this week and I'm not sure what would have changed to cause the behavior.

This is a Ubuntu 22.04 dual-boot on a Lenovo Thinkpad laptop with Win 10 on the other partition.

**Edit:**
As described, this boot wasn't 'problematic' insofar I was able to get into Ubuntu having removed the problem drive.  Details below:

```
chris@chris-X1C6:~$ systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 13.643s (firmware) + 14.975s (loader) + 1.833s (kernel) + 1min 30.460s (userspace) = 2min 912ms
graphical.target reached after 29.201s in userspace

chris@chris-X1C6:~$ systemd-analyze blame
26.476s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 9.421s plocate-updatedb.service
 6.576s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 5.565s gpu-manager.service
 5.252s plexmediaserver.service
 4.160s qemu-kvm.service
 2.784s snapd.service
 1.436s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
 1.274s mysql.service
  731ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0c2e04fe\x2d9691\x2d4db4\x2da0c1\x2dabc269f2460c.service
  686ms dev-loop30.device
  683ms dev-loop22.device
  678ms dev-loop29.device
  675ms dev-loop33.device
  674ms dev-loop31.device
  674ms dev-loop34.device
  673ms dev-loop32.device
  670ms dev-loop26.device
  670ms dev-loop24.device
  669ms dev-loop25.device
```

Nothing from today in the `syslog` `grep`ing on either 'warning' or 'error'--is a lot of output though (redirecting to file outputs over 38MB)

Comment: Any errors reported in /var/log/syslog?  Sounds like hardware --  cable to failing disk.  Can you switch cables/enclousre?  Can you run a smart check on the disk (smartmontools package)?

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.